# Wordpress - Retrieve permalinks of posts in a php generated html code

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

Ok, so i have created a post slider that contains 10 posts.

I have a php code that generate the slider and make each of these posts to have a specific class (small, middle, large image)

Problem: 
I can't retreive the post link so it can be clickable.
$post->post_title

How can i add the:
$post->post_title

The code looks like this:

```
if($index === 0){
    $output .= "<div class=\"page page-one\">";
}
$itemClass = $index < 2 ? "item-size-medium" : "item-size-small";
$img = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post, 'large');
$output .= <<<HTML
<div class="item $itemClass">
    <div class="item-img">
        <img src="$img">
    </div>
    <div class="item-title">
        <h1>
            <a href="#">$post->post_title</a>
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
HTML;


if(($index !== 0 && ($index%5) === 0) || 1 == 2){
    $output .= "</div>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What's up Dragos. Assuming you're inside a loop (you referenced $post), you can use `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">permalink</a>` or likely it'll be within the `$post` object if looping over a WP_Query. [Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink)